# How do I create circles connected with elastic lines in Processing.js?

Tags: processing.js

In Processing.js, I'd like to have circles that represent nodes, with lines connecting linked nodes. I'd like those connected circles to naturally pull toward each other with a kind of elasticity of the lines, and the circles to bounce against each other when they touch. Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Well, there's this: http://processingjs.org/source/head-animation.pjs

But none of it seems elastic, and there's no bouncing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this sample might get you going in the right direction:

- [Box2D.JS with Processing.js](http://processingjs.org/source/box2d/box2d.html)

It has the circles, the lines, and the bouncing.

Answer (score 0):

Or if you want it yourself this is the Google search term you're looking for:
http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=force+directed+graph+javascript&aq=f&aqi=g-c1&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=

The base algorithm is pretty simple, getting a tuned example to work a little less so. I've looked through this stuff before, but this quick search just turned up this little js project that seems to do it quite properly: http://github.com/jackrusher/jssvggraph

Shouldn't be too difficult to port.